# Spotlight Crashing after upgrading to Mac OS X 10.6.4

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, spotlight

After updating to 10.6.4 spotlight suddenly stopped working in terms of constantly crashing..
I have tried rebuilding the index and I currently have no haxies whatsoever installed on my machine.

Comment: Can you post the Crash Report (`~/Library/Logs/Diagnostic Reports`)? Additionally what method did you use to rebuild the index?

Answer (score 0):

fixed it, reinstall os X